# Equivalent code of CreateObject of VB in c#

Tags: c#

I have a code in VB.  how to write it in C#. This code is below:

```
Set server = CreateObject("FaconSvr.FaconServer")  
'Create the FaconServer object
server.OpenProject ("C:\Program Files\fatek\FaconSvr\Example\VB\DEMO.fcs")
'Open the project file(Demo.fcs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("FaconSvr.FaconServer"));
```

Comment: Thanks, But i get error : 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type'

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error message when trying to activate a "MyNamespace.MyClass" COM dll. I can call the COM object from VBA but not from C#.